# Issues reading a multiline field in mini-XML 2.7

Tags: c, xml, multiline

I am using C with mini-XML 2.7, and reading a XML doc. All is fine, except that my XML has a section that looks like this:

```
<layer name="pattern1" width="100" height="40">
<data encoding="csv">
970,970,970,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,
1089,0,4,765,21,
0,1089,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
  </data>
 </layer>
```

My code parses all the XML down here flawlessly. Then I attempt to read the CSV values, by using this:

```
s = mxmlGetText(node, &has_space);
```

But right after that, a `printf()` statement like this

```
printf("s='%s'", s);
```

Shows **only** the first line.

```
970,970,970,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
```

I would like to read the lines below the first line, but tried to use `mxmlGetText()` again with no luck. And all the lines are shown by using `mxmlSaveFile()`.

How can I get all the lines? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this issue.

1.-Loaded the XML file using MXML_OPAQUE_CALLBACK instead MXML_TEXT_CALLBACK in the call to mxmlLoadFile().

2.-Used mxmlGetOpaque() instead mxmlGetText().

Now my code works flawlessly.